# Formula to compare cells in 2 different sheets, copy text and highlight new or updated cells using different colours

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I am looking for some help with a Macro in excel.

1 workbook with 3 worksheets in it.
Worksheet1 & 2 (WS1 & WS2) has data copied from a business reports.
WS3 has a consolodated view so all of WS1 is copied to this sheet but also some columns from WS2.

I need a Macro that would compare WS1 columns A to J to the data held in WS3 columns A to J if nothing exist in those columns within WS3 then the macro will copy the populated cells from WS1 to WS3 and Highlight the cells using a colour for the background or text.(say red)

If there is data in WS3 and the data in WS1 for the same cell is different it would copy the data and highlight the cells background or text in a different colour(different to red)

If the data in a cell for both WS1 & WS3 are the same then do nothing.

The cells align so A1 :J500 in WS1 will copy to the same in WS2.

I realise I have just written the logic here however I am unsure if it will work with free text as that's what is in some of the field.

If you need more information let me know and I can call, give my number or provide the information by message.

It would be great if someone could help me.

Does anyone know of a formula that I could use to achieve the above, a macro or even just a youtube video that could help me?

Jay

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A screen cap or two (upload to http://imgur.com and link to them) and the formulas you have tried you help clarify things

Comment: You want a *formula* that *performs* a conditional action (copy if). That is not possible without writing code.

Comment: @Jan Doggen, I didnt think it was but my knowledge is limited. Thank you for letting me know. I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no formula in Excel like IF(A1<>B1,COPY(A1, B1)) - with good reason. It means one cell's formula could modify another cell or potentially itself, thereby possibly creating circular/endless loops or overwriting its own formula.

What you can do is create another sheet, called it WS4. In WS4 cell A2, put

```
=IF(ISBLANK(WS3!A2), WS1!A2, WS3!A2)
```

Now create 2 conditional formatting formulae in WS4!A2

```
=ISBLANK(WS3!A2)         ....format red

=WS1!A2<>A2              ....format blue
```